# Pandas fillna the same value in a column, but different per column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains NA's, I need to fill the NA's with some value, however I need the same value per column, but every column must be different.
I cannot use a dictionary for column to NA value mapping as I don't know how many columns due to the data being imported from an API.

I am using python 3

sample of DF and expected output:

DF:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: what are the values you want to fill the columns with? Provide an example

Comment: I've updated the question with an example

Comment: Please provide text data and not image. Copy paste the data as text

Comment: must the filled value be different from all the values in the column? or can it be any random value which might also be in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craft a dictionary with replacement values for each column containing NAs (here I'm using ascii uppercase letters, but you can use whatever source):

```
s = df.isna().any()
d = dict(zip(s[s].index, ascii_uppercase))
# {'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'D': 'C', 'E': 'D'}

df = df.fillna(d)
```

output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  -  -  -  -  D
1  A  B  -  -  -
2  A  -  -  C  D
```

used input:

```
     a    b  c    d    e
0    -    -  -    -  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  -    -    -
2  NaN    -  -  NaN  NaN
```

###### alternative method to craft the dictionary

```
s = df.isna().any()
d = {k: v*3+'|' for k,v in zip(s[s].index, ascii_uppercase)}
# {'a': 'AAA|', 'b': 'BBB|', 'd': 'CCC|', 'e': 'DDD|'}
df = df.fillna(d)
```

output:

```
      a     b  c     d     e
0     -     -  -     -  DDD|
1  AAA|  BBB|  -     -     -
2  AAA|     -  -  CCC|  DDD|
```

Comment: thanks, this works as expected. I have used ascii_uppercase how do you know of a way to add ascii_uppercase with a '|' so first column would be A | , next column would be B |.
I tried my own list as "A|B|C" but the '|' gets assigned out too.

Comment: see alternative, I also showed how to multiply the characters like in your initial question

Comment: works as expected. thank you

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
maps = {col: i for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)}
df = df.fillna(maps)
```

Comment: I think this has the potential to work, but I get the error:

ValueError: Cannot set non-string value '5' into a StringArray.

column 5 is the first column with a NA

Comment: Try this: `maps = {col: (str(i) if df[col].dtype == 'object' else i) for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)}`

Comment: still gives me the same error unfortunately